# UV texture's color is set to all model in collada loader of three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

first of all sorry for my bad english.
I have a problem with collada loader of three js, i have a cylinder in blender with a UV texture on it and i render it there everything is perfect but when i export it and load it in three js collada loader the color associated with image is applied to whole model like this. 
[The model in my browser](http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a492/gc210797/Untitled_zpsfc52e90c.png)
The original color of the model is red.

I am loading my model like this:

```
 var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

  loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

  loader.load( 'untitled.dae', function ( collada ) {

    var dae = collada.scene;

    var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

dae.position.set(0,0,0);
dae.scale.set(25,25,25);
```

[My collada file if u want to see it.](http://pastebin.com/8rE0KtLE)
What i am doing wrong here? is there a problem the way i am exporting missing some attribute while exporting? i am new to web 3D programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did was i was not creating 2 different materials 1 for color and other for the texture and i shifted to obj/mtl from collada importer and it solved my problem also remember to clip the image texture in blender texture settings under image sampling.